# The theory of the result obtained from repeated square root operation of numbers

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Why do I always get 1 when I keep hitting the square root button on my calculator?”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3283/why-do-i-always-get-1-when-i-keep-hitting-the-square-root-button-on-my-calculato)

Take any positive number above or below 1. Upon performing repeated square root operations the end result is always 1. Is there a theorem in Math that can prove this rather intriguing result? Thank you.
Klim

Answer (score 6):

You have the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_n}$

For $0 \lt x_1 \lt 1$, we have that $x_{n+1} \gt x_n$ and $x_n \lt 1$. So this is a monotonically increasing sequence bounded above, and so has a limit.

The limit $L  = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ satisfies $0 \lt x_1 \le L \le 1$ and $L = \sqrt{L}$, thus $L = 1$.

If $x_1 \gt 1$, you get a monotonically decreasing sequence which is bounded below and you get $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 1$, similarly.

Note that, if you don't start with $1$ (or $0$), in a finite number of steps, you will get very close to $1$, but don't really attain $1$. The result of $1$ you see is likely due to the precision limitations of your calculator.